# Microphone not working on third party apps only (iPhone 6)

Tags: iphone, siri, microphone, third-party

Recently my iPhone's mic has stopped working but solely for third party apps such as Whatsapp, Snapchat & Telegram.

I have tried the following:

- Restarting my phone
- Updating my phone to the latest version
- Using compressed air to clear any debris

I have tested the mic via phone call, facetime & siri and these all work fine as expected.

Has anyone experienced this issue? The only remaining thing that I feel as though I can try is a factory restore which I'm trying to avoid.

Any suggestions would be helpful as I haven't found anything through apple support guides for this issue.

Comment: I have this problem too! I hope you find an answer soon.

Comment: I have the same problem with my iPhone 7. I haven't found an obvious pattern to which apps work and which don't; for instance, it seems to work fine when recording a video with the Camera, but not when using Voice Memos. I've tried a factory restore and that hasn't fixed it, so next step is taking it in for repair, I guess.

Comment: @miles I forgot to update this post after I found the problem,  the issue is there are two microphones on iphones one that is for "on-speaker" and another for "on-call".  The microphone jack that can be found next to the audio jack is clogged with lint.  You can use a small needle can pry out whats in there, or better yet take your phone apart and air blast it with compressed air.

Answer (score 1):

Under `Settings` > `Privacy` > `Microphone` you'll be able to allow/deny each app that require the microphone to use it.

Comment: Just checking, did you mean `Privacy` instead of `Confidentiality`? I'm not aware of a Confidentiality option, although that may depend on your language/region.

Comment: Yeah I think that's it (I said confidentiality because in French this menu is called "Confidentialité"). I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the apps are all enabled to use voice, I tried toggling the settings on and off also.

Comment: Ok, and does the microphone work on Apple pre-installed apps **with and without** speaker mode?

Comment: Interesting! So it appears to work when speaker mode is on but not when off.

Comment: I don't know for sure about the iPhone 6, but in several iPhones, there is one mic for "classic" conversation (phone at your ear) at the bottom, and another _somewhere_ else because the first one would be too near the loudspeaker.